# Typescript want promise declaration for target esnext

Tags: typescript

We wanted to start part of your project in typescript, as we would like to move onto TS as whole, but I have trouble configure environment.

Here is my simple tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "files": [
        "./player.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015",  // Should be redundant
            "es2016",  // Should be redundant
            "es2017",  // Should be redundant
            "esnext"
        ],
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "types": [],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
    }
}
```

The file I have is not having any ES5 features enabled. As if the options got completely ignored.

The `tsconfig.json` and `player.ts` are on same folder level (thought it is not root).

I am using TypeScript v 2.9.1. I have used TypeScript multiple times before and this never happens... not sure what to do about it.

Comment: Is there another file `tsconfig.json` in your project? Can you provide an example of code that doesn't compile?

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Obviously, this isn't possible, and the reason why this happens is specific to your case. Most likely tsconfig.json isn't picked up for some reason, e.g. you provided arguments for `tsc`.

Comment: Where should I put it thought... I have tried moving/coping it to root too, for no avail.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it somehow. Few things I learned troughs the way:

If compiled file (root file) is not in root folder, it will cause problems. If you simply run `tsc /inner/file` it won't work, **but** if you put `-p` flag there it will read the file once again.

This wasn't solution for me as I used webpack (in non root folder), so I had to do few changes:

*I used `awesome-typescript-loader` as it supports TS 2.x*

I have added `configFileName` to the loader options. Not using `TsConfigPathsPlugin` at all. With this all my errors about ES2015 vanished.

I now got few with unable to resolve, so I had to add extensions to resolve. Worked.

But now I got some test files from PHP codebase (`resources.ts`) compiling, so I had to add context to loader options.